# Проблема с изменением значения gcc -D

Tags: c++, linux, c

Добрый день, проблема при переопределении значения OS через 
gcc -D OS=2 tst.c
После выводит что значение переопределено

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define OS 1

#if OS == 1
#define DATA "LOLLY\n"
#else
#define DATA "NOT_LOLLY\n"
#endif

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf(DATA);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нут так оно действительно переопределено, чем тут удивлятся?

Comment: да,но по факту значение не меняется.

Comment: @Alabama Funny: Разумеется, не меняется. Более позднее определение (в коде) все равно "побеждает". Только выдается предупреждение о переопределении. Что именно вас в этом случае удивляет?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> #define OS 1
> ```

```
#ifndef OS
  #define OS 1
#endif
```

Comment: Описка, однако.

Comment: @0andriy, исправил :)